# 404 not found error in jQuery AJAX call to Spring controller

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, spring

I am newbie in Spring. I generate the JSON like below:

```
[
    {
        "customer" : "16", "project" : "19",
        "phase" : "47", "approver" : "5",
        "date1" : "", "date2" : "",
        "date3" : "", "date4" : "",
        "date5" : "", "date6" : "",
        "date7" : "", "activity" : "1"
    },

    {
        "customer" : "17", "project" : "20",
        "phase" : "48", "approver" : "3",
        "date1" : "", "date2" : "",
        "date3" : "", "date4" : "",
        "date5" : "", "date6" : "",
        "date7" : "", "activity" : "1"
    }
]
```

I am passed this JSON to my Spring controller:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'NewTimesheet',
    dataType : 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),

    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I am mapped the request to controller like below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="NewTimesheet", headers = { "Content-type=application/json" })
@ResponseBody
public String addNewTimesheet(@RequestBody List<Timesheet> timesheet,
    HttpSession session) {

    logger.info("timesheet list size is" + timesheet.size());
    return "success";
}
```

`Timesheet` class:

```
public class Timesheet {
    private String project;
    private String phase;
    private String approver;
    private String customer;
    private String date1;
    private String date2;
    private String date3;
    private String date4;
    private String date5;
    private String date6;
    private String date7;
    private String activity;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

But my request is not mapped with the conroller. My console displays like below:

> WARN
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.handleNoSuchRequestHandlingMethod:142
>   - No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/NewTimesheet', method 'POST', parameters
>   map['[{"customer":"16","project":"19","phase":"47","approver":"5","date1":"","date2":"","date3":"","date4":"","date5":"","date6":"","date7":"","activity":"1"},{"customer":"17","project":"20","phase":"48","approver":"3","date1":"","date2":"","date3":"","date4":"","date5":"","date6":"","date7":"","activity":"1"}]'
>   -> array['']]

How to map my JSON to controller? Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Have you included all the necessary Jackson dependencies in your project (core and databind)?

Answer (score 3):

You need to annotate the class as Controller, add a RequestMapping in your class and the HTTP method your calling in your method.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/NewTimesheet")
public class MyClassName {

        @RequestMapping(value={ "", "/" }, method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = { "Content-type=application/json" })
        @ResponseBody
        public String addNewTimesheet(@RequestBody List<Timesheet> timesheet,HttpSession session){
                 logger.info("timesheet list size is"+timesheet.size());
                 return "success";
        }
}
```

Comment: it's not work for me.i put the annotaion in class level

Comment: Did you add the method = RequestMethod.POST as well? Is it giving the same error?

Answer (score 2):

Change @RequestBody to @ModelAttribute before the list in the controller. And in your json, put 'timesheet.' before every field, that is, timesheet.customer,timesheet.project.... such like that. That would work.

Answer (score 2):

A couple things that might be causing problems for you:

1. Make sure you have all of the necessary dependencies for Jackson.  For Maven, this would be:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.2</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.2</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. You don't need to stringify your JavaScript object, this is done implicitly.  You should also name your submitted variable, since it must map to the domain object:

   ```
   $.ajax({
       method : 'post',
       url : 'NewTimesheet',
       dataType : 'json',
       data:{ 'timesheet': jsonObj },
       success : function(data) {
           console.log(data);

       }
   });
   ```
3. Your controller should be configured to explicitly handle a POST request.  Setting the accepted content type in the headers is not necessary.  Also, I believe you need to map your domain objects to an array and not a list:

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value="NewTimesheet", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public @ResponseBody String addNewTimesheet(@RequestParam("timesheet") Timesheet[] timesheet,HttpSession session){
            logger.info("timesheet list size is"+timesheet.length);
            return "success";
   }
   ```

If you are using a relatively recent version of Spring MVC, there is no additional configuration required to handle requests for and producing JSON.  Your AJAX request specifies a JSON response, which Spring will recognize and delegate to Jackson for serializing the input and output.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `method=post`. also I added `produces = "application/json"`

```
@RequestMapping(value="NewTimesheet", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
        @ResponseBody
        public String addNewTimesheet(@RequestBody List<Timesheet> timesheet,HttpSession session){
                 logger.info("timesheet list size is"+timesheet.size());
                 return "success";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my ajax request i added the contentType:application/json.After adding this  controller mapped my ajax request.Thanks for all.